# International Power Converter

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I am going out of th country in a few weeks, and I am planning on taking my Macbook. I have a power adapter for the country I'm visiting, but it was bought for a PC. Will it work on a Mac?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a power converter, as Apple power supplies will all take 100-240V at 50 or 60 Hz, so a simple mechanical adaptor will do. Having said that, anything that will work with a PC power supply should also work with a Mac.